# test server for upload files - android

Tags: android, file-upload, retrofit2

I am using retrofit library in my android app. I read multiple tutorial about upload and download files and working with json data. most of these tutorial have worked with image for simplicity and there is some API for working with that like imagur, but I want to work with audio files in my app and I don not know any server or API  for testing upload and download mp3 files. can anybody introduce me some of that?

**update :** 
How can I make my own computer for testing? is this possible?

Comment: The type of file you wanna upload is irrelevant. If you can upload a jpg then you can upload a mp3. Of course you can install a webserver on a pc in your lan. And a little script.

Comment: I do know it. and I run some sample but I want to show some demo so I need it

Answer (score 0):

There are so many Linux servers and which are free. Try https://www.hostinger.in/
for free domains and 1gb disk size.

Furthermore, if you want to test on your own computer try wamp,xampp or IIS (for .NET) and publish your code over there.